# Issue with packed texture images

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, uv, packed-data

I've just ran into something annoying when packing textures. As you can see when texture image is packed it is all over the place. This just started to happen today and I'm completely lost as of what would cause this... I read on another forum that it might have to do with file directory so I tried different locations on my hard drive but no change.

Did anyone encounter this issue before? I would really appreciate any help/pointers as I'm completely stuck and unable to send off things to render farm.

Thanks!!

[image]
image unpacked
[image]
image packed

[image]
nodes

Comment: Problem only with TIFF or PNG acts the same?

Comment: It seems as it changes color space to Color instead of Non-Color which should be used for normal map when texture's packed. Though this shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED

The color mode in the properties panel was still set on sRGB and over-riding the texture node set in non-color data. Still don't know why it started to happen only now. But all sorted!

[image]